# Doctrine2: Uni-directional @OneToMany with foreign key?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a "Product" entity with many "Video" entities, and I only need a unidirectional @OneToMany with foreign key (one product, many videos).  My Product-side "key" is not primary or unique, which is why I need it to be unidirectional (eg, "select * from videos where product_family = 2143")

I'm using Doctrine 2.1

Is there yet a way to do uni-directional @OneToMany with only a foreign-key in Doctrine 2.1?  If not, soon?

```
UPDATE: I found a relevant quote from Roman Borschel on May 2010:
```

*"this would need quite some special-case handling in many places. In the light that there are 2 reasonably good alternatives (mapping through a jointable or simply making the association bidirectional) **we do not consider this something that really needs to be done.**"*

Has this opinion by the Doctrine2 team changed?

Comment: I also have similar issue and I don't want to add join-table or make the association bidirectional. In my case the 2nd entity shall know nothing about it's owning entity, so this is really an issue in Doctrine2.

Answer (score 0):

OneToMany by design has the related ID on the `"Many"` side of the relationship. So to make the child table relate to the parent without an additional field in a join table is not possible.